# how to add more storage plugins programatically in apache drill?

Tags: apache-drill

I tried **drill JDBC driver** to query programmatically.

Useful portion of code:

```
Connection conn = new Driver().connect("jdbc:drill:zk=local", getDefaultProperties());
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("show databases");
        while (rs.next())
        {
            String SCHEMA_NAME = rs.getString("SCHEMA_NAME");
            System.out.println(SCHEMA_NAME);
        }

public static Properties getDefaultProperties()
  {
    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(ExecConstants.HTTP_ENABLE, "false");
    return properties;
  }
```

Everything worked fine till I have `cp` & `dfs` storage plugin. Output of above query:

```
INFORMATION_SCHEMA
cp.default
dfs.default
dfs.root
dfs.tmp
sys
```

But when I added `mongo` as storage plugin with configuration:

```
{
  "type": "mongo",
  "connection": "mongodb://localhost:27017/",
  "enabled": false
}
```

I got following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to deserialize "/tmp/drill/sys.storage_plugins/mongo.sys.drill"
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:66)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:69)
    at net.hydromatic.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:126)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:78)
    at com.mkyong.App.main(App.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to deserialize "/tmp/drill/sys.storage_plugins/mongo.sys.drill"
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.sys.local.FilePStore.get(FilePStore.java:140)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.sys.local.FilePStore$Iter$DeferredEntry.getValue(FilePStore.java:219)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.StoragePluginRegistry.createPlugins(StoragePluginRegistry.java:168)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.StoragePluginRegistry.init(StoragePluginRegistry.java:132)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.run(Drillbit.java:244)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:100)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not resolve type id 'mongo' into a subtype of [simple type, class org.apache.drill.common.logical.StoragePluginConfig]
 at [Source: [B@21318883; line: 2, column: 3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.unknownTypeException(DeserializationContext.java:849)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:167)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:99)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:84)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:132)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:41)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1269)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:912)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.sys.serialize.JacksonSerializer.deserialize(JacksonSerializer.java:44)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.sys.local.FilePStore.get(FilePStore.java:138)
    ... 10 more
```

**Also, how can I add plugin configuration programmatically?**

> **Edit:** Similar behaviour for hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drill provides a REST API. I've used the curl command shown in the [docs](http://apache.github.io/drill/docs/plugin-configuration-basics/#storage-plugin-rest-api):

```
curl -X POST -/json" -d '{"name":"myplugin", "config": {"type": "file", "enabled": false, "connection": "file:///", "workspaces": { "root": { "location": "/", "writable": false, "defaultInputFormat": null}}, "formats": null}}' http://localhost:8047/storage/myplugin.json
```

Comment: I am able to perform the task using RestAPI. But unable to do using it's JDBC jar